# Add new items with load more button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactJS and I am trying to add a load more button that loads new posts every time it's clicked on. There are no page numbers in the API and that is what is used in all the examples I saw so far. I am not sure how to implement it to my below code. I have also integrated a search function for the list of items. Can anybody please help me? I have attached my App component below. I need to add a simple load more button. I am not sure how to display the allData before filtering in different pages.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [allData,setAllData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData,setFilteredData] = useState(allData);

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let result = [];
    console.log(value);
    result = allData.filter((data) => {
    return data.title.search(value) != -1;
    });
  setFilteredData(result);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    setFilteredData(response.data);
    })
  .catch(error => {
  console.log('Error getting fake data: ' + error);
  })
  }, []);

  const styles = {
    display:'inline',
    width:'30%',
    height:50,
    float:'left',
    padding:5,
    border:'0.5px solid black',
    marginBottom:10,
    marginRight:10
    }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>Search:</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event) =>handleSearch(event)} />
      </div>
      <div >
        {filteredData.map((value)=>{
          return(
        <div>
          <div style={styles} key={value.id}>
          <img
                className="card--image"
                alt={value.title}
                src={value}
                width="50%"
                height="50%"
              ></img>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })}
    </div>
    <button onClick={handleShowMorePosts}>Load more</button>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your code is loading 5000 photos. You have to use an API where you can state a) the start index b) the length, then keep track of those values in your component state. Using an API that always loads all data completely negates implementing a loadMore button.

Comment: Typicode seems to support pagination already: https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder/issues/27

Comment: @ChrisG Is there no way to slice the data into parts and display part by part. The API does not have any index or page no.

Comment: Of course you can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array, like any other array.